# jQuery Mobile - value of slider always zero

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I'm attempting to get the values of dynamically generated sliders. Unfortunately, no matter what I do they always return a value of either "0" or null. I can't figure this out...

Here's the HTML code that I am working with:

```
<input type="number" data-type="range" class="init_slider ui-input-text ui-body-b 
ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-slider-input" name="init_slider_0" id="init_slider_0" 
min="-5" max="30" />

   <div role="application" class="ui-slider-track ui-btn-down-b ui-btn-corner-all">

      <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" 
data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" 
data-theme="b" role="slider" aria-valuemin="-5" aria-valuemax="30" aria-valuenow="14" 
aria-valuetext="14" title="14" aria-labelledby="init_slider_label_0" style="left: 
54.285714285714285%;"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span></span></a>
   </div>
```

And my JS (it may be inefficient, but I'm just trying to get this to work):

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {
 $(".init_slider").change(function() {
    var init_data = {};
    $.each(".init_slider_label", function(index, option) {
        char_name = $("#init_slider_label_"+index).text();
        var init_val_desc = $("#init_slider_"+index).next();
        var init_val_foo = $(init_val_desc).children("a")[0];
        var init_foo = $(init_val_foo);
        var init_val = $(init_foo).attr('aria-valuenow');
        init_data[char_name] = init_val;
     });
   });
});
```

The value of init_val always seems to end up as "0" or just nothing, depending on what I'm trying.

I don't think the issue is specific to sliders either because when I change them to simple text fields, I have the same problem: always returning a value of '0'. So I wonder if it has to do with how I'm calling this code. As you can see in my example above, I'm doing it with 'pageshow'. But I have the same problem after a button click.

Anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamically injected items, you should bind events this way.

```
$(document).on("change", ".init_slider", function() {
 var slider_val = $(this).val();
 console.log(slider_val);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b9TP3/)**

Comment: Omar: you are amazing! I am now able to capture to value of the slider! The only trick is I need to capture the values for multiple sliders with different IDs, but now I get the concept. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: @mrbranden you're welcome :) if you need further assistance, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found binding was not working, but shall try method above, to solve it I added hidden inputs, updated the hidden input val on each slider change etc..